# Improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{a x^2 + bx + c} dx$, $a > 0,a x^2 + bx + c>0$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have a question about improper integral. If you can help me , I appreciate that.

If a > 0 and the graph of $y=a x^2 + bx + c$ lies entirely above the x-axis, show that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{a x^2 + bx + c}=\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{4ac - b^2}}.
$$

Comment: i fixed it for you this time, but be so nice and learn to use the math editor properly

Comment: Completing the square first; Then, the appropriate change of variable.

Comment: Thank.I know generally using but I'm not use so much often so it will be forgetten :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I did like that but ı conclude same answer with times a.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you are right .I'm sorry about that.I correct now.

Comment: $a$ must disappear. Check the antiderivative..

Comment: You're from Turkey, right? I can tell from the capital 'I's with dots.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes , I'm :)

Comment: *Yes, I am. (You can't contract "pronoun-verb" at the end of a sentence. If you were to say "I am Turkish," the word "am" wouldn't be stressed, because the word "Turkish" would get stressed instead, so you'd be able to contract it to "I'm Turkish." However, in the sentence "I am," the word "am" _is_ stressed, because there's no object to stress instead. So you can't contract it.)

Comment: Honestly, I had to look that up. I knew that it was wrong because it _sounds_ wrong. But I didn't know the reason that it was wrong.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Sorry about the mistake.I'm still preparation school(Basic English Departmant) at university.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $ax^2+bx+c$ has real roots then the integral doesn't exists, since we will end up with an integral of the form $$\dfrac1{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}$$where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, which clearly diverges. Hence, we can assume that the discriminant is strictly negative, i.e., $4ac -b^2 > 0$.

Given that $4ac-b^2>0$, we have $ax^2+bx+c = a\left(x+\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + c - \dfrac{b^2}{4a}$. Hence, letting $y=x+\dfrac{b}{2a}$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{ax^2+bx+c} & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{dy}{ay^2 + c-\dfrac{b^2}{4a}} = \dfrac1{a} \dfrac1{\sqrt{c/a-b^2/(4a^2)}}\left. \arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{c/a-b^2/(4a^2)}}\right)\right \vert_{-\infty}^{\infty}\\
& = \dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks I understand the second part but why if the equation has real root , integral doesn't exis ? and how it's diverge. I'm finding 0.

Comment: @Leth If $\alpha = \beta$, clearly the integral diverges. If $\alpha \neq \beta$, then the principal value if zero but not the integral, since if we split the integral as one over $\dfrac1{x-\alpha}$ and $\dfrac1{x-\beta}$, then the integral of both doesn't exist.

Comment: oh I get that.Thanks for the clarification.